# Link button with selected radio button in list view

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

**Goal**

For learning purpose, I have created a `custom list view` with `5 items`. `Each Item` will have `question, choices, check` button.

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View row, ViewGroup parent){

    this.view = row;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if(row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_row_qs, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.chapName=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.question);
        viewHolder.rb0 = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.choice0);
        viewHolder.rb1 = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        viewHolder.rb2 = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        viewHolder.rb3 = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.choice3);
        viewHolder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.check);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.chapName.setText(questions[pos].getQuestionDescr());
    viewHolder.rb0.setText(questions[pos].getChoice()[0]);
    viewHolder.rb1.setText(questions[pos].getChoice()[1]);
    viewHolder.rb2.setText(questions[pos].getChoice()[2]);
    viewHolder.rb3.setText(questions[pos].getChoice()[3]);
    //viewHolder.button.setId(pos);
    //viewHolder.rg.setId(pos);
   /* viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, ((RadioButton) view.findViewById(((RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rg)).getCheckedRadioButtonId()))+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });*/

    return row;
}
```

This is how I set my items. As you see, I have `TextView, 1 radio group, 4 radio button, 1 button` in the view holder.

`Question` is a class which holds all the contents of each row. So I pass `array of question objects to this adapter`.

**Doubt**

When user clicks on a check button, it has to find the selected radio button and checks against the answer. Answer will also be part of Question class.Toast the result.

How do I do this? I am stuck on this. I am not able to find how to link it?

If it is `html`, I could set `Id` for `div` which holds `row item` and from button click, I will get the parent Id and from the parent Id I can get selected radio button and I can check the stored answer against the selected value.

**More explanation**

```
  Question1
     choice0    choice1
     choice2    choice3
                    CHECK
  Question2
     choice0    choice1
     choice2    choice3
                    CHECK
  Question3
     choice0    choice1
     choice2    choice3
                    CHECK
  Question4
     choice0    choice1
     choice2    choice3
                    CHECK
  Question5
     choice0    choice1
     choice2    choice3
                    CHECK
```

This is how my layout will look like. As you see in my `getView` method I have given `id` for the elements at the layout itself. So it takes same Id for all the elements :(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `OnClick` passes the `View` that was clicked, i.e. the "check" button.

So you can do:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    View rowView = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
    RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rg);
    long selectedId = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    // Check if selected id is correct
    Toast.makeText(context, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Also, since the `OnClick` code is the same, it's better practice to create it only once and hook it up when creating the `ViewHolder`.